# EF 6 Code First Object Life Cycle/Signals/Events

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a code-first model:

```
public class Organization
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

I want Created/Updated dates to be automatically assigned whenever the model is created/updated. I have seen some examples of doing this in the context but that just seems *wrong*. What is the correct way to do this?

For example, in Django I could use the `django.models.signals.pre_save` or `django.models.signals.post_save` to modify the object pre/post save.

Or am I going about this all wrong, and I should be using another approach all together?

Comment: Doing it in the context does not seem too wrong to me. The context is aware of the moment objects are saved and there is no wiring whatsoever between DbContext sand POCO's. (Notice the word _between_). Personally Nevertheless, I think it _is_ wrong, because I think this is should be done by database triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can plug-in your custom OnUpdate and OnCreate logic. You need to override `SaveChanges()` and also add abstract class that we will call `Entity`. Then you inherit `Entity` in your model class which means that now you can call OnUpdate/OnCreate functions inside your model and those will be automatically injected.

Here is what it would look like for your example.

**YourDataContext.cs**

```
namespace YourProject.Models
{
    public class YourDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var changedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries();

            foreach (var changedEntity in changedEntities)
            {
                if (!(changedEntity.Entity is Entity)) continue;
                var entity = (Entity)changedEntity.Entity;

                switch (changedEntity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entity.OnBeforeInsert();
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entity.OnBeforeUpdate();
                        break;

                }
            }

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public virtual void OnBeforeInsert() { }
        public virtual void OnBeforeUpdate() { }
    }
}
```

**Organization.cs**

```
public class Organization : Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public override void OnBeforeInsert()
    {
        this.Created = DateTime.Now;
        this.Updated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public override void OnBeforeUpdate()
    {
        this.Updated = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems good, but I have to imagine EntityFramework has something like this already.

Comment: I don't think it does. This is as flexible as you can get to have your models standartized beforeupdate/beforeinsert functions inside them.

Comment: Isn't that a double cast anti pattern in the foreach loop? http://www.boyet.com/Articles/DoubleCastingAntiPattern.html

Answer (score -1):

How about this one

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), DataMember]
public DateTime Created{ get; private set; }


[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), DataMember]
public DateTime Updated{ get; private set; }
```